# At the heart of the party/in the center of the party/at the center of the party

Tags: american-english

I have a questing regarding space prepositions.

For instance, if I want to specify that a woman and I are dancing at the central part of a room where a loud party is taking place, would it be correct for me to say “We are dancing at the heart of the party”?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. *Heart of the party* is a figure of speech and not necessarily a *central* location, a *physical* location, or even a location at all.

Comment: So, that being the case... could you please tell me how should I say that I'm dancing with some one in the center of a room where a party is taking place? In other words; can I say that "We are in the center of the party?" "At the core of the party?" "At the center of the party"? Is one of those examples correct in terms of specifying that we are in the center of the actions that are taking place in that particular event?

Comment: You just did :) . Also, although the phrase is a figure of speech, that on its own doesn't mean *you* can't use it, so long as it makes sense in the context of your essay / book / etc. If you're interested in the *writing* aspect, as opposed to the purely *English* aspect of this, you might be interested in the [Writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange community.

Comment: I'm moving to the writers stack exchange website, but, before I do, could you please write which one of my examples was correct? I'm confused... did you just say that the figure of speech use was correct to indicate that I was at the central part of the location where the party was taking place?

Comment: It's context-dependent. Yes, "heart of the party" *can* mean what you intend, but if you had "She was the heart of the party and he was ..." in a sentence nearby, then it might be awkward to reuse the phrase in its physical sense. Then again, if you had something like (excuse the poor composition) "She was the heart of the party; celebration was the heart of the party; and they danced at the heart of the party", where it's clear that you're playing with the phrase, then it might be ok again. Hope this helps :) .

Comment: I would go with _at_ over _in_ in your two examples ("at the heart/center of the party" rather than "in the heart/center of the party"). The reason, I suspect, has to do with Lawrence's observation that the party has a figurative heart or center, not a geometrical one—and for reasons I can't explain _at_ seems to capture that figurative sense better than _in_ does. Perhaps someone at Writers SE will have a better argument.

Answer (score 1):

In general the heart of the party would be understood to be at the focal point of the party as would to a lesser extent the centre.

For the location, or time period, it would seem more natural to use the word middle.

"Our slow dance, in the middle of the party room, became the centre of attention and the very heart of the party from the moment it started."